# SQL JOIN multiplication of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have 3 tables with varios datasets.
One of these Tables has more fields like all others.

i have to join it for SQL reporting services. But the problem is, if i join the values, i get the following result:

```
TABLE 1       TABLE 2
|ID|          |ID|Calls|
|--|          |--|-----|
| 1|          | 2|    7|
| 2|          | 3|    8|
| 3|          | 4|    9|
```

With a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
|ID|Calls|
|--|-----|
| 1|    7|
| 2|    8|
| 3|    9|
```

The third table:

```
|ID|DNIS|Calls|
|--|----|-----|
| 1|4711|    2|
| 1|4712|    3|
| 1|4713|    2|
| 2|4714|    2|
| 2|4715|    3|
| 2|4716|    3|
| 3|4717|    4|
| 3|4718|    3|
| 3|4719|    2|
```

Together with FULL JOIN

```
|ID|Calls|DNIS|Calls|
|--|-----|----|-----|
| 1|    7|4711|    2|
| 1|    7|4712|    3|
| 1|    7|4713|    2|
| 2|    8|4714|    2|
| 2|    8|4715|    3|
| 2|    8|4716|    3|
| 3|    9|4717|    4|
| 3|    9|4718|    3|
| 3|    9|4719|    2|
```

Thr Problem is the mutiplcation iof field Calls. The sums in Report are all 3 times higher. This constuct is totally dynamical and cant catch hardcoded. So I'm looking for a dynamically possibility. What I need is something like this.

```
|ID|Calls|DNIS|Calls|
|--|-----|----|-----|
| 1|    7|4711|    2|
| 1| NULL|4712|    3|
| 1| NULL|4713|    2|
| 2|    8|4714|    2|
| 2| NULL|4715|    3|
| 2| NULL|4716|    3|
| 3|    9|4717|    4|
| 3| NULL|4718|    3|
| 3| NULL|4719|    2|
```

Do you have an idea?

My testquery looks like this
    DECLARE @t1 TABLE (
        id INT
    )

```
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 2
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 3

SELECT * FROM @t1

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (
id INT
,calls INT
)

INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT 1,3
INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT 2,4
INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT 3,5

DECLARE @t3 TABLE (
    id INT
    ,DNIS INT
    ,cnt INT
)
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 1,1,3
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 1,2,4
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 1,3,5

INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 2,1,3
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 2,2,4
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 2,3,5

INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 3,1,3
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 3,2,4
INSERT INTO @t3 SELECT 3,3,5

SELECT
    t1.id
    ,t2.calls
    ,t3.DNIS
    ,t3.CNT
FROM
@t1 as t1
FULL JOIN
@t3 as t3
on t1.id = t3.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
@t2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Most people avoid this by rolling up the results in separate queries/subqueries.  What's the final form of the data desired - is it actually that table with nulls, or are you planning on rolling it up further?

Comment: No, that table with nulls is the final result for my report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your query to return nulls for `Calls` all but the first row with a given ID, you could do something like this:

```
  -- Column names must be unique.  You have two columns for Calls, so I'm 
  -- renaming them here as Calls1 and Calls2.
  ;
  WITH data1 AS (
     select  ID
             Calls1
          ,  DNIS
          ,  Calls2
     from [your query]
  )
  ,  data2 as (
     select *
        ,   RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DNIS) 
     from   data1
 )
 select  ID
    ,    Calls = CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Calls1 ELSE Null END
    ,    DNIS
    ,    Calls2
 from    data2
```

Comment: no, unfortunaltely i have not always four elements. Its totally dynamical. I'm testing the Textbox property just now

Comment: @Frank  I've added another suggestion, this time for the underlying query.

Comment: hmm, looks like. But the id is not always 1. The id can be everythin between 1 and 9999999.

Comment: @Frank Actually, I just realized I left out the `Partition` clause.  But in any case, I'm not testing ID for the value 1, I'm testing the column RowNumber that I created.

Comment: @Frank The `Row_Number()` function assigns a number to each row, restarting with each new value of ID (that's what the `Partition` clause does) and assigning them in ascending order by DNIS within the same value of ID.  So the first row for each value of ID will have the RowNumber value 1.

Comment: thats looks great but the query won't run, if i past my query in your query. brace error and syntax error near the keyword 'ORDER'. I don't understand ;with - unfortunately...

Comment: Replace all of `[your query]` with your query, even the braces.  Also, I put in a comma that doesn't belong.  I'll fix the syntax.

Comment: Also, don't forget to replace "Calls2" with "Cnt".

Answer (score 1):

With out using two CTE's

```
SELECT 
        T1.id,
        CASE 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T3.DNIS)= 1 THEN T2.calls 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS Calls
    ,   T3.DNIS
    ,   T3.cnt

FROM @t1 T1
     FULL JOIN @t3 T3 ON T3.id = T1.id
     LEFT JOIN @t2 T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
```